# MemoryError when running Numpy Meshgrid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have **8823** data points with x,y coordinates. I'm trying to follow the answer on [how to get a scatter dataset to be represented as a heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369492/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set) but when I go through the

`X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)`

instruction with my data arrays I get `MemoryError`. I am new to numpy and matplotlib and am essentially trying to run this by adapting the examples I can find.

Here's how I built my arrays from a file that has them stored:

```
XY_File = open ('XY_Output.txt', 'r')
XY = XY_File.readlines()
XY_File.close()

Xf=[]
Yf=[]
for line in XY:
    Xf.append(float(line.split('\t')[0]))
    Yf.append(float(line.split('\t')[1]))
x=array(Xf)
y=array(Yf)
```

Is there a problem with my arrays? This same code worked when put into [this example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/hexbin_demo.html) but I'm not too sure.

Why am I getting this MemoryError and how can I fix this?

Comment: This is unrelated to your memory problems (which are due to making a *huge* meshgrid from these tiny things), but the nicestway to loop over a file is `with open('XY_Output.txt', 'r') as f: for line in f:`. The `with` ensures the file gets closed *no matter what* and looping over the file keeps it from being read into memory at once. (This isn't the memory problem here, but it's still needless.)

Comment: Thank you for this tip Mike but this doesn't seem to work in Python 2.5 which is what I'm running. (at least it gives me an error stating that the 'as' is reserved in python 2.6) Am I correct? It is a much simpler way of doing it, that's true...

Comment: You can add `from __future__ import with_statement` at the top. But you can still improve the code by moving the readlines statement to `for line in XY_File.readlines()` and putting the close at the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your call to `meshgrid` requires a lot of memory -- it produces two 8823*8823 floating point arrays. Each of them are about 0.6 GB.

But your screen can't show (and your eye can't really process) that much information anyway, so you should probably think of a way to smooth your data to something more reasonable like 1024*1024 before you do this step.

Comment: Am I not calculating `8823 * 8823 * 8 bytes = 600 MB` or so correctly? In any event, it's realistic that this 1.2GB could push the limits of a normal machine.

Comment: So that's what's happening! I knew I didn't want a 8823x8823 image. What I want is to take all those data points and reflect their occurence rate on an image, converting a scatter plot that would have many overlapping dots to a heatmap that shows a higher incidence in some areas. Do you mind taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369492/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set and also reply there if you know how I could achieve this? 

I'm going to mark this answer as accepted because it explains the problem in my question.

Comment: meshgrid could be a pre-processing step and not used directly for drawing

Answer (score 8):

in numpy 1.7.0 and newer `meshgrid` has the `sparse` keyword argument. A sparse meshgrid is setup so it broadcasts to a full meshgrid when used. This can save large amounts of memory e.g. when using the meshgrid to index arrays.

```
In [2]: np.meshgrid(np.arange(10), np.arange(10), sparse=True)
Out[2]: 
[array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]), array([[0],
    [1],
    [2],
    [3],
    [4],
    [5],
    [6],
    [7],
    [8],
    [9]])]
```

Another option is to use smaller integers that are still able to represent the range:

```
np.meshgrid(np.arange(10).astype(np.int8), np.arange(10).astype(np.int8),
            sparse=True, copy=False)
```

though as of numpy 1.9 using these smaller integers for indexing will be slower as they will internally be converted back to larger integers in small (np.setbufsize sized) chunks.

Answer (score 0):

When you call np.meshgrid for scatter figure, you need to normalize your data if it is too large to process, try this module

```
    # Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
st = StandardScaler()
X = st.fit_transform(X)
```