# ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. model n_feature> input nfeature

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to implement isolation forest for 9 input features 
Used the  example from 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_isolation_forest.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-isolation-forest-py

My train and test set has 9 features and hence I am creating Xtrian and Xtest of same feature size

```
X.shape 
(100, 9)
 >> X_train.shape
(200, 9)
```

My code :

```
print(__doc__)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

# Generate train data
X = 0.3 * rng.randn(100, 9)
X_train = np.r_[X + 2, X - 2]
# Generate some regular novel observations
X = 0.3 * rng.randn(20, 9)
X_test = np.r_[X + 2, X - 2]
# Generate some abnormal novel observations
X_outliers = rng.uniform(low=-4, high=4, size=(20, 9))

# fit the model
clf = IsolationForest(max_samples=100, random_state=rng)
clf.fit(X_train)
y_pred_train = clf.predict(X_train)
y_pred_test = clf.predict(X_test)
y_pred_outliers = clf.predict(X_outliers)

# plot the line, the samples, and the nearest vectors to the plane
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5, 5, 50), np.linspace(-5, 5, 50))
Z = clf.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)

plt.title("IsolationForest")
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Blues_r)

b1 = plt.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c='white')
b2 = plt.scatter(X_test[:, 0], X_test[:, 1], c='green')
c = plt.scatter(X_outliers[:, 0], X_outliers[:, 1], c='red')
plt.axis('tight')
plt.xlim((-5, 5))
plt.ylim((-5, 5))
plt.legend([b1, b2, c],
           ["training observations",
            "new regular observations", "new abnormal observations"],
           loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

But I am getting error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 9 and input n_features is 2
```

In my case my error shows : Model n_features is 9 and input n_features is 2

Any inputs on what I am missing here:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you've fit a model with 9 features, the plotting section of the code is still presuming only two dimensions, as was the case in the example you're working off of:

```
# plot the line, the samples, and the nearest vectors to the plane
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5, 5, 50), np.linspace(-5, 5, 50))
Z = clf.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
```

Look at the shape of the `np.c_()` array being passed into `clf.decision_function()`:

```
np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()].shape
(2500, 2)
```

You're getting the error because `clf` is expecting 9-D input, but you're only providing a 2-D array.

The classifier itself should still be accessible without any trouble.  You can still use `decision_function()` and `predict()` methods, for example, but you won't be able to plot all 9 dimensions using the code you're going off of - it was only designed to plot in 2-D.  Even running `np.meshgrid()` with 9 dimensions will almost certainly throw a `MemoryError` - see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460627/memoryerror-when-running-numpy-meshgrid) for more on that.

Trying to plot 9-D space isn't going to be very helpful here, anyway.  You might focus instead on more standard visual representations of classifier strength, like [`ROC curves`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html) or even a good old fashioned [`confusion matrix`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html).

Comment: thanks for the insight! i was expecting some kind of label prediction results for y_pred_test = clf.predict(X_test)
y_pred_outliers = clf.predict(X_outliers) but it didnt give me any results.. so is there something missing there or  will i be able to generate confusion matrix from it?

Comment: Try running your code up to the line `y_pred_outliers = clf.predict(X_outliers)`, you should get some output.  (I just ran your code without the error-causing part, and it worked up to that line.)  You can generate a confusion matrix using `y_pred_outliers` as `y_pred` in `confusion_matrix()`, and a vector of length `y_pred_outliers` consisting of `-1` as `y_true`.  But keep in mind that this example you're working on was designed to show very clear cases of anomalies/outliers - you're likely to get 100% true positives out of `predict()`, given `X_outliers` as input.