# How to mesh grid before plottiong any variable in a netCDF file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, latitude-longitude, netcdf, netcdf4

So I am plotting the column concentration plot and before that i have to make a mesh grid but if I directly write:

```
lons,lats= np.meshgrid(lon,lat)

x,y = map(lons,lats)
```

Then it produces the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-cdc15fcf5910> in <module>()
----> 1 lons,lats= np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
      2 
      3 x,y = map(lons,lats)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in 
meshgrid(*xi, **kwargs)
   4696 
   4697     if copy_:
-> 4698         output = [x.copy() for x in output]
   4699 
   4700     return output

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in 
<listcomp>(.0)
   4696 
   4697     if copy_:
-> 4698         output = [x.copy() for x in output]
   4699 
   4700     return output

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py in wrapped_method(self, *args, **params)
   2573     """
   2574     def wrapped_method(self, *args, **params):
-> 2575         result = getattr(self._data, funcname)(*args, **params)
   2576         result = result.view(type(self))
   2577         result._update_from(self)

MemoryError:
```

But in all tutorial, I see they didn't get this error. Help!!!

Comment: so sorry to post such a question...adding sparse = 'True' to 1st line resolves the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MemoryError when running Numpy Meshgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460627/memoryerror-when-running-numpy-meshgrid)