# Memory error if not using Standard Scaler

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have read here https://towardsdatascience.com/do-decision-trees-need-feature-scaling-97809eaa60c6 and watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmBqnKSSKfM&ab_channel=KrishNaik video which stated that you don't need to use Standard Scaler for Decision Tree machine learning.

But, what happened is on my code is the opposite. Heres the code I am trying to run.

```
# importing libraries  
import numpy as nm  
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import pandas as pd  
  
#importing datasets  
data_set= pd.read_csv('Social_Network_Ads.csv')  
  
#Extracting Independent and dependent Variable  
x= data_set.iloc[:, [2,3]].values  
y= data_set.iloc[:, 4].values  
  
# Splitting the dataset into training and test set.  
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(x, y, test_size= 0.25, random_state=0)  
  
#feature Scaling  

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler    
st_x= StandardScaler()  
x_train= st_x.fit_transform(x_train)    
x_test= st_x.transform(x_test)  


#Fitting Decision Tree classifier to the training set  
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier  
classifier= DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', random_state=0)  
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I continue the question on the part which I try to visualize the data. Here's the code.

```
#Visulaizing the trianing set result  
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap  
x_set,y_set = x_train, y_train
x1, x2 = nm.meshgrid(nm.arange(start = x_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = x_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step  =0.01),  
nm.arange(start = x_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = x_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))  
mpl.contourf(x1, x2, classifier.predict(nm.array([x1.ravel(), x2.ravel()]).T).reshape(x1.shape),  
alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('purple','green' )))  
mpl.xlim(x1.min(), x1.max())  
mpl.ylim(x2.min(), x2.max())  
for i, j in enumerate(nm.unique(y_set)):  
    mpl.scatter(x_set[y_set == j, 0], x_set[y_set == j, 1], c = ListedColormap(('purple', 'green'))(i), label = j)  
mpl.title('Decision Tree Algorithm (Training set)')  
mpl.xlabel('Age')  
mpl.ylabel('Estimated Salary')  
mpl.legend()  
mpl.show()
```

The output is succeed **if I ran it with the StandardScaler**. The graph is showed nicely. But, as I hashed (comment) the StandardScaler part, it stated the **Memory Error.**

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-1282bf709e27> in <module>
      3 x_set,y_set = x_train, y_train
      4 x1, x2 = nm.meshgrid(nm.arange(start = x_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = x_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step  =0.01),  
----> 5 nm.arange(start = x_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = x_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))  
      6 mpl.contourf(x1, x2, classifier.predict(nm.array([x1.ravel(), x2.ravel()]).T).reshape(x1.shape),  
      7 alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('purple','green' )))  

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in meshgrid(*xi, **kwargs)
   4209 
   4210     if copy_:
-> 4211         output = [x.copy() for x in output]
   4212 
   4213     return output

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   4209 
   4210     if copy_:
-> 4211         output = [x.copy() for x in output]
   4212 
   4213     return output

MemoryError:
```

The error only occurs on the visualizing part; in the other part of the code such prediction works nicely without the Standard Scaler.

Can the Decision Tree work without Standard Scaler? If yes, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decision Tree can work without Standard Scaler and with Standard Scaler. The important thing to note here is that scaling the data won't affect the performance of a Decision Tree model.

If you are plotting the data afterwards though I imagine you don't want to plot the scaled data but rather the original data; hence your problem.

The simplest solution I can think of for doing this is to pass `sparse=True` as an argument to `numpy.meshgrid` as that seems to be what's throwing the error in your traceback. There's some detail on that in a past question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460627/memoryerror-when-running-numpy-meshgrid)

So applied to your question, that would mean you change this line:

```
nm.meshgrid(
    nm.arange(start=x_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop=x_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step=0.01),  
    nm.arange(start=x_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop=x_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step=0.01),
)
```

to

```
nm.meshgrid(
    nm.arange(start=x_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop=x_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step=0.01),  
    nm.arange(start=x_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop=x_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step=0.01),
    sparse=True,
)
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion to add the `sparse=True` but it showed `TypeError: 'sparse' is an invalid keyword argument for arange()`.

Comment: I understand what you said about Standard Scaler does not give a significant impact to the ML. this error probably occur on the visualization part as it cost a bunch of large data.

Comment: I think you need to make sure you are passing sparse=True as a keyword argument to np.meshgrid not np.arange. Try closing a bracket before you write sparse=True

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found how to solve this. I just make the Standard Scaler remain where it written. The scaled data is worked on visualization part due to the scaled data (caused the data to scale down to be plotted on the graph)

Otherwise if I want to use the not scale data, I just can write

`classifier.(x,y)`

My reason to use the non-scale data is to create a code that can predict any input from the machine learning which is below,

```
# this will work well if NOT using Standard Scaler
classifier.fit(x, y) 
estimated_salary = input("Enter your salary:")
age = input("Enter your age:")


purchase = classifier.predict([[estimated_salary, age]])

print("If your salary is", estimated_salary, "and your age is", age , "this is your purchase result:", purchase)
```

Thank you for the people who inspired and gave some idea on this. I appreciate it.