# Scatter plot with a huge amount of data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to use [Matplotlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) to generate a scatter plot with a huge amount of data (about 3 million points). Actually I've 3 vectors with the same dimension and I use to plot in the following way.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import rc
import pylab
from pylab import * 
fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.scatter(delta,vf,c=dS,alpha=0.7,cmap=cm.Paired)
```

Nothing special actually. But it takes too long to generate it actually (I'm working on my MacBook Pro 4 GB RAM with Python 2.7 and Matplotlib 1.0). Is there any way to improve the speed?

Comment: Beyond tens of thousands of points, some form of raster graphing might be preferable both for speed and actual usability.

Comment: You should pick an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @NickT How can you raster a pyplot graphics?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could take the heatmap approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369492/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set).  In this example the color represents the quantity of data in the bin, not the median value of the dS array, but that should be easy to change.  More later if you are interested.

Comment: but, the heat map is not a good idea for anomaly detection using scatter plot.

Comment: @ChHaXam Good point. You can, however, overlay a scatter plot (of outliers) on top of the heat map and get the best of both.

Answer (score 29):

Unless your graphic is huge, many of those 3 million points are going to overlap.
(A 400x600 image only has 240K dots...)

So the easiest thing to do would be to take a sample of say, 1000 points, from your data:

```
import random
delta_sample=random.sample(delta,1000)
```

and just plot that.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
import random

fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

N=3*10**6
delta=np.random.normal(size=N)
vf=np.random.normal(size=N)
dS=np.random.normal(size=N)

idx=random.sample(range(N),1000)

plt.scatter(delta[idx],vf[idx],c=dS[idx],alpha=0.7,cmap=cm.Paired)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, if you need to pay more attention to outliers, then perhaps you could bin your data using `np.histogram`, and then compose a `delta_sample` which has representatives from each bin.

Unfortunately, when using `np.histogram` I don't think there is any easy way to associate bins with individual data points. A simple, but approximate solution is to use the location of a point in or on the bin edge itself as a proxy for the points in it:

```
xedges=np.linspace(-10,10,100)
yedges=np.linspace(-10,10,100)
zedges=np.linspace(-10,10,10)
hist,edges=np.histogramdd((delta,vf,dS), (xedges,yedges,zedges))
xidx,yidx,zidx=np.where(hist>0)
plt.scatter(xedges[xidx],yedges[yidx],c=zedges[zidx],alpha=0.7,cmap=cm.Paired)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: To complete the solution,if you were to sample randomly do it N times to get the whole picture of the situation.

Comment: Actually I also think that binning data could be the easiest way. Can you please suggest me how to make it (conserving the correspondence betweens the bins of the three vectors? I mean a sort of 3D histogram)

Comment: thank you very much. Actually I think I did not explain my self correctly. I would like to create a colormap so that the colors indicates the average values of variables z in the bin (xbin,ybin) in order to plot it as an imshow. This is different I think with respect to np.histogramdd. Maybe someone could help me

Answer (score 13):

What about trying [pyplot.hexbin](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/hexbin_demo.html)?  It generates a sort of heatmap based on point density in a set number of bins.