# Converting a matrix into an image in Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, matrix, matplotlib

I would like to save a numpy matrix as a .png image, but I cannot do so using the matplotlib since I would like to retain its original size (which apperently the matplotlib doesn't do so since it adds the scale and white background etc). Anyone knows how I can go around this problem using numpy or the PIL please? Thanks

Comment: see `fig.figimage` http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.figimage

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910388/matplotlib-plot-small-image-without-resampling/9915223#9915223

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902761/saving-a-numpy-array-as-an-image

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've solved it using scipy and posted the answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using scipy library

import scipy.misc

...(code)

scipy.misc.imsave(name,array,format)

or

scipy.misc.imsave('name.ext',array) where ext is the extension and hence determines the format at which the image will be stored.