# 2D pixel plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pixel, reshape

I have a question regarding 2D pixel plots similar to this:
[Make a 2D pixel plot with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6323737/4762680)

The provided answer works, but I would like to change the direction of y axis.
My code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
grid = a.reshape(3, 3)

plt.imshow(grid, extent=(x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()), interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.jet, aspect="auto")
```

The problem is that after the reshape, the grid looks like this:

```
>grid
   array([[1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9]])
```

For the plot I want to make, I would need a grid like this:

```
>grid
 array([[3, 6, 9],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [1, 4, 7]])
```

I have looked into options of reshape but could not find anything that helped. 
Any advice on how I could change my grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
grid.T[::-1]
```

or

```
a.reshape(3,3).T[::-1]
```

This transposes the matrix and reverses the ordering of the rows which gives you the correct shape.

Reversing the order of the rows can also done in `imshow` using `origin`

```
plt.imshow(grid.T,origin='lower', ...)
```