# Plotting a 2D scatter plot with color heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I would like to make a 2D scatter plot `(x,y)` and the color of the point is `value` (from 0 and 1) with a heatmap legend,
using the following dataset:

```
x y value
3 2 0.1
2 1 0.2
...
```

I checked both [Plotting a 2D heatmap with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282368/plotting-a-2d-heatmap-with-matplotlib) and [Make a 2D pixel plot with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323737/make-a-2d-pixel-plot-with-matplotlib)
but none of them supports what I am looking for.

Comment: What is your input format? A csv file? A pandas dataframe? A list of lists? And a heatmap legend requires somewhat a heatmap, which you don't produce with `plt.scatter(x, y, c = value)`. Are you looking for `plt.colorbar()`?

Answer (score 4):

This is no problem:

`plt.scatter(x=x, y=y, c=value)`

`c` stands for color/colormap.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `plt.scatter`?