# how to have co-occurence matrix from top 2000 features

Tags: python-3.x

i have 'document' list of 5000 words. I have 'top_2000_features' list  cosnsiting of 2000 words  from that 'document' list of 5000 words. Now i want to plot coccurence matrix on top_2000_features with window size =2 .
How to do that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhBGZ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scatter plot with a huge amount of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082298/scatter-plot-with-a-huge-amount-of-data)

Comment: No, the folliwng link doesnt give relevant response to my query!

Comment: can anyone please respond to my query!

Comment: Do you need a correlation matrix plot?

Comment: no i dont need correlation matrix plot or scatter plot , i just need co-occurence matrix .No plot i require.

Comment: Hm, your title clearly states "plot".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814452/co-occurrence-matrix-from-list-of-words-in-python/42814963

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574257/constructing-a-co-occurrence-matrix-in-python-pandas

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=co+occurrence+matrix+python

Comment: your confusing ,this 'plot' i said in conventional manner not scatter plot or correlation plot ot  any ML plot