# Generate a heatmap in MatPlotLib using a scatter data set

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization, heatmap

My question is almost exactly similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369492/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set). **However**, I'm not satisfied with the answers, because I want to generate an actual heatmap, without explicitely binning the data.

To be precise, I would like to display the function that is the result of a convolution between the scatter data and a custom kernel, such as 1/x^2.

How should I implement this with matplotlib?

**EDIT**: Basically, what I have done is [this](https://github.com/joelthelion/mtgox_chart/blob/master/plot_btc.py). The result is [here](http://sd-12155.dedibox.fr/~joel/btc/mtgox.png). I'd like to keep everything, the axis, the title, the labels and so on. Basically just change the plot to be like I described, while re-implementing as little as possible.

Comment: Do you want guidance or the actual code? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you looked at `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde`?  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html It does exactly what you want.  (Though it uses `exp(-x)` instead of `1/x^2`.) You'll need to customize it to use something other than a guassian kernel, but that's not difficult to do.

Comment: @Joe Kington: my problem is not really computing the convolution, but rather how to display it into a nice graph.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Convert your time series data into a numeric format with matplotlib.dats.date2num.  Lay down a rectangular grid that spans your x and y ranges and do your convolution on that plot.  Make a pseudo-color plot of your convolution and then reformat the x labels to be dates.

The label formatting is a little messy, but reasonably well [documented](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/dates_api.html).  You just need to replace AutoDateFormatter with DateFormatter and an appropriate formatting string.

You'll need to tweak the constants in the convolution for your data.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import pylab as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates

t0 = dt.date.today()
t1 = t0+dt.timedelta(days=10)

times = np.linspace(dates.date2num(t0), dates.date2num(t1), 10)
dt = times[-1]-times[0]
price =  100 - (times-times.mean())**2
dp = price.max() - price.min()
volume = np.linspace(1, 100, 10)

tgrid = np.linspace(times.min(), times.max(), 100)
pgrid = np.linspace(70, 110, 100)
tgrid, pgrid = np.meshgrid(tgrid, pgrid)
heat = np.zeros_like(tgrid)

for t,p,v in zip(times, price, volume):
    delt = (t-tgrid)**2
    delp = (p-pgrid)**2
    heat += v/( delt + delp*1.e-2 + 5.e-1 )**2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.pcolormesh(tgrid, pgrid, heat, cmap='gist_heat_r')

plt.scatter(times, price, volume, marker='x')

locator = dates.DayLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.AutoDateFormatter(locator))
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image: Script output]

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! I just have one concern with your answer: how can I keep the nice axis labeling I have in my current version? (see my edits)

Comment: I would convert your time series data to a numerical representation al la datetime.date.today().toordinal() or matplotlib.dates.date2num().  pcolormesh(). Then figure out how to format the x labels.  This last part has me stumped.