# converting diurnal scatter plot into heatmap plot

Tags: matplotlib, histogram, heatmap, scatter

I have created a diurnal plot of date vs. time but it is rather messy and I'd prefer to create a heatmap. Something similar has been done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387819/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set), but it doesn't work as I can't parse the time in as well. I tried this which works for the x-axis but I can't do the y.

[image]
Ideally, it would have a legend on the size showing how much data is in each 2D bin. How do I parse the x and y axis in such that numpy.histogram2D/imshow can read it or meshgrid/pcolormesh can be used?

Comment: Could you post your data?

Comment: You can clone the repo for yourself and run it if you like. https://github.com/bgriffen/emailify