# Heatmap that shows both high and low density regions clearly (python)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, data-visualization, heatmap

I have a data set I would like to represent as a heatmap (x,y positions). A couple of areas are of much higher density than the rest of the region. This has had the result of these high density regions completely washing out the detail of the lower density regions.

I think using a Gaussian KDE provides the best representation (and looks the nicest) compared to say 2d histograms or contour plots, so would prefer solutions using this method.

I **can't post images** because this account has less than 10 rep, but [here are some examples of what I've tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJRo2.jpg).

My code snippets are based on already posted snippets that I link below rather than repost (some are rather lengthy), but I'll edit to include them if asked.

The first few are based on Ivo Bosticky's code in this question: [Efficient method of calculating density of irregularly spaced points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652671/efficient-method-of-calculating-density-of-irregularly-spaced-points). The images there are the 'style' that I'm after.
As shown in the album linked above, with a small gridsize the low density regions are hard to make out, no real detail. Higher gridsizes show some splotchier detail, but really not a smooth transition from the high density to low density. Putting values on a logscale washes out the whole thing on lower resolutions, and with higher resolutions shows detail but doesn't appropriately blend the grid.

The second couple in that album are based on the [scipy.stats.gaussian_kde](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) example. Changing the gridsize seems to have essentially no effect, and the logscale washes it all out again.

So the **TLDR:** How do I make a 2D Gaussian KDE that shows the detail smoothly in both high and low density regions?

Comment: One option you might consider is to put a scatterplot over a filled contour plot. Say, filter the data for the scatter to meet some criteria and basically overlay that on the filled contour.

Comment: I've actually done that, and the filled contour plot shows the detail best of all my various attempts. However it has artefacts that misrepresent the underlying data (for example, consistently showing diamond shapes around areas that are not that shape). I'm also trying to avoid showing the individual points for this particular plot, so avoiding scatter plots

Comment: I routinely do filled contours with an overlaid line contour plot over, and I force the same number of contours. Perhaps if you did something similar, but forced a different number? Like the filled contour has 50 and the lines has 10? You can also do in-line labels on the lines to indicate the levels.

Comment: I'm not sure that would help the issue I mention. [see here for what I mean by the 'diamonding'](http://i.imgur.com/Htxkh7C.png)

Answer (score 1):

The most naive way to represent scattered data is using scatter plots. Of course, the problem is that once a certain point density is reached, a scatter plot provides no further information. In that case, we use histograms or heatmaps based on some KDE. These methods however invariably remove detail in the less dense areas of our dataset.

My suggestion for showing both therefore would be to make a scatterplot colored by your kde values. E.g. as

```
pyplot.scatter(your_x,your_y,c=your_kde_value,marker='.',linewidth=0)
```

Here, `your_kde_value` is an array containing the value of the KDE function at the points of your scatter plot (i.e. it should have the same shape as `your_x` and `your_y`.

Results might look like this (using a sample of 10000 points from a bivariate normal distribution:

[image]

As you can see, the color information provides all the detail in the center, whereas we still retain the outlying points.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not sure this would work so well, as there are areas with no data and areas with only scattered points (i.e. pretty low density). I would prefer something with a smooth gradient covering the full space. I will try your suggestion anyway and get back to you.

Comment: Also as a general comment (newbie), does convention dictate that I upvote your answer because it is a legitimate attempt to solve my problem and provides a nice example, or leave it unvoted because it's not quite what I'm after?

Comment: @Funkosaurus you can upvote every answer you feel is helpful and then "accept" the one answer that best answers your question. So if you had 10 answers, 5 of which were helpful and one of those was the best, you could upvote the 5 and then accept the best one.

Comment: @Christoph I've tried your suggestion using your syntax but keep running into an error. The "your_kde_value" I use is the same variable I've been using to plot the album images using imshow. The error:
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "[ *list of numbers*]" length of rgba sequence should be either 3 or 4.

Comment: @Funkosaurus: You need to calculate the value for your KDE at the sample points, not provide a grid. Then you provide the array of KDE values at these points to the plot command. I will edit my post to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that illustrates my suggestion - this is based on [this matplotlib example:](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/pcolormesh_levels.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



# make these smaller to increase the resolution
dx, dy = 0.01, 0.01

# generate 2 2d grids for the x & y bounds
y, x = np.mgrid[slice(1, 5 + dy, dy),
                slice(1, 5 + dx, dx)]

z = np.sin(x) ** 10 + np.cos(10 + y * x) * np.cos(x)

plt.contourf(x,y,z, 20, cmap = 'rainbow')    #change these levels
plt.contour(x,y,z, 5, colors = 'k', linewidths = .25) #and here

plt.show()
```