# Method for calculating irregularly spaced accumulation points

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am attempting to do the opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652671/efficient-method-of-calculating-density-of-irregularly-spaced-points): Given a 2D image of (continuous) intensities, generate a set of irregularly spaced accumulation points, i.e, points that irregularly cover the 2D map, being closer to each other at the areas of high intensities (**but without overlap!**).

My first try was  "weighted" k-means. As I didn't find a working implementation of weighted k-means, the way I introduce the weights consists of repeating the points with high intensities. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

def accumulation_points_finder(x, y, data, n_points, method, cut_value):
    #computing the rms
    rms = estimate_rms(data)
    #structuring the data
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=False)
    if cut_value > 0.:
        mask = data > cut_value
        #applying the mask
        X = X[mask]; Y = Y[mask]; data = data[mask]
        _data = np.array([X, Y, data])
    else:
        X = X.ravel(); Y = Y.ravel(); data = data.ravel()
        _data = np.array([X, Y, data])

    if method=='weighted_kmeans':
        res = []
        for i in range(len(data)):
            w = int(ceil(data[i]/rms))
            res.extend([[X[i],Y[i]]]*w)
        res = np.asarray(res)
        #kmeans object instantiation
        kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=n_points, n_init=25, n_jobs=2)
        #performing kmeans clustering
        kmeans.fit(res)
        #returning just (x,y) positions
        return kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

Here are two different results: 1) Making use of all the data pixels. 2) Making use of only pixels above some threshold (RMS).

[image: Without threshold]

[image: With threshold]

As you can see the points seems to be more regularly spaced than concentrated at areas of high intensities.

So my **question** is if there exist a (deterministic if possible) better method for computing such accumulation points.

Answer (score 1):

Partition the data using quadtrees (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) into units of equal variance (or maybe also possible to make use of the concentration value?), using a defined threhold, then keep one point per unit (the centroid). There will be more subdivisions in  areas with rapidly changing values, fewer in the background areas.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great idea! I will study this method, and try to adapt it to my requirements.