# Python: How to plot a heatmap for coordinates with different color intensity or different radius of circles?

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib, heatmap

Given some data in three lists, for example:

```
latitudes = [50.877979278564,48.550216674805,47.606079101562,50.772491455078,42.451354980469,43.074657440186,44.044174194336,44.563243865967,52.523406982422,50.772491455078]
longitudes = [4.700091838837, 9.038957595825, -122.333000183105, 7.190686225891, -76.476554870605, -89.403335571289, -123.070274353027, -123.281730651855, 13.411399841309, 7.190686225891]
counts = [15, 845, 2, 50, 95, 49, 67, 32, 1, 88]
```

which can be interpreted as: The coordinate of `i` which is (`latitudes[i]`, `longitudes[i]`) occures `counts[i]` times on the map.

I want to generate a heatmap with an appropriate scale. The cordinates should be represented by colour filled circles. The diameter of the circles should somehow represent the count of the corresponding coordinate.

(As an alternative I thought about representing the count by colour intensity. I don't know which is best or if these two represantations can be combined.)

**How can do I realize such a heatmap? (I assume it is called so?)**

Perhaps it is relevant to mention the amount of data I am dealing with:

- `sum(counts)` is about 1.000.000
- there are around 25.000 different coordinates.

Comment: Perhaps this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369492/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scatter` is the method you are looking for, at it has two optional parameters to either adjust the size (with keyword `size` or just `s`) or the color (with keyword `color` or `c`) of each point, or you can do both simultaneously. The color, or heatmap effect, is probably better for the density of points you have.

Here's an example of using this method:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

NPOINTS = 1000

np.random.seed(101)
lat = np.random.random(NPOINTS)*8+44
lon = np.random.random(NPOINTS)*100-50
counts = np.random.randint(0,1000,NPOINTS)

plt.subplot(211)
plt.scatter(lat, lon, c=counts)
plt.colorbar()
plt.subplot(212)
plt.scatter(lat, lon, s=counts)

plt.savefig('scatter_example.png')
plt.show()
```

Resulting in:

[image]

If you choose to use `size`, you might want to adjust the count values to get a less crowded plot, for example by extending the above example with:

```
plt.figure()
COUNT_TO_SIZE = 1./10
plt.scatter(lat, lon, s=counts*COUNT_TO_SIZE)
plt.savefig('scatter_example2.png')
```

You get a cleaner plot:

[image]

I've of course accidentally swapped latitude and longitude from their normal axes, but you get the idea :)

Comment: This is great, thanks! Now I am trying to scale the map, too, since scaling the "counts" is not enough. Would be so kind to tell me how this is done? I looked up the method [scatter()](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) but I couldn't find any parameters to achieve that. Where can I tell matplotlib to set the "map" bigger, so the points are getting a little more separated?

Comment: I'm curious, what do you mean by 'scaling the "counts" is not enough.' Are you using counts to set the size or the color? If you are using it to set the color and the circles that are generated are too dense, you can set the size `s` to a scalar: `s=5`. This sets every point to have the same size. The default size is 20, and this represents the diameter squared, so s=5 is circles with half the size.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. :-) I'll try to explain again. What you showed me in your answert works great. I understand how to scale the circles. What I want to achieve now is to make the x and y axis "longer". I am exploring the mathplotlib library at the moment and I found this: `xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()`. It returns -200.0 and 200.0 right now. If both axis would return -20000.0 and 20000.0 the axis would be longer preserving the scale, resulting in the circles to have more room around them. At the moment it looks like [this](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=33mapp4&s=5).

Comment: Just scaling the latitudes and longitudes by e.g. 100 does not seem to work. :-)

Comment: There are two options: (1) use xlim and ylim to "zoom" into a continent, making a figure for each one, or (2) make a very big figure use http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure `figsize` to set the size in inches and or `dpi` to control the dots-per-inch. You can also consider scaling counts non-linearly, maybe by setting the size to `s=counts*counts*COUNTS_TO_SIZE` and adjust the constant so that the biggest dot is not too big... I will try to come up with an example and add it to the answer...

Comment: by "zoom" I mean set the xlim and ylim range to smaller set of the total range, so in my example above, I would do `plt.xlim(44,46)` and `plt.ylim(-50, -30)` to plot only the lower left corner of data.

Comment: Thanks again for these awesome instructions!

Answer (score 0):

In a general answer for any graphics library, you would want to do something like this:

```
maxSize = 10 #The maximum radius of the circles you wish to draw.
maxCount = max(counts)

for lat, long, count in zip(latitudes, longitudes, counts):
    draw_circle(lat, long, count/maxCount*maxSize) #Some drawing library, taking x, y, radius.
```

`zip()` allows you to join your three lists and iterate over them in one loop.

Dividing the count by the maximum count gives you a relative scale in size, which you then multiply up by the size you want the circles to be. If you wanted to change the colour too, you could do something like:

```
maxSize = 10 #The maximum radius of the circles you wish to draw.
maxCount = max(counts)

for lat, long, count in zip(latitudes, longitudes, counts):
    intensity = count/maxCount
    draw_circle(lat, long, intensity*maxSize, Color(intensity*255, 0, 0)) #Some drawing library, taking x, y, radius, colour.
```

Producing a sliding scale from black to red as intensity increases.

You may need to adjust the latitude and longitude values to produce sane x and y values, depending on the size you want in your final image and the values you are going to put in. If you find your counts get too large to display, and the smaller items too small when lowering the max size, you might want to consider a logarithmic scale instead of linear for the intensity.

Implementing this with an actual graphics library should be trivial, but depends on the library itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure on the heat map, but to plot with coloured circles of different sizes you can use:

```
   from matplotlib import pyplot    

   pyplot.scatter(longitudes,latitudes,counts,c=rgb)
   pyplot.show()
```

where rgb is a 2-d array of user defined rgb values, something like:

```
   maxcount = float(max(counts))
   rgb = [[ 1, 0.5, x/maxcount ] for x in counts]
```

or however you wish to define your colours.