# How to place country boarders as background for a plot with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, background-image

I have some data made of coordinates and the count of each coordinate which I plot in a heatmap like this:

```
pyplot.subplot(211)
pyplot.scatter(longitudes, latitudes, c=counts)
pyplot.colorbar()
```

which is inspired by [this great answer here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9569236/641514).

If you [look closely](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=33mapp4&s=5) you can see, that the dots shape the worldmap somehow. To underline this effect I'd like to put the real country boarders (simply drawn would be enough) as background to my plot. Is this possible with matplotlib? Maybe there is some (hidden) builtin in matplotlib?

Answer (score 1):

You can likely achieve this if you have some image of the world map that you want as a background.  You can read this into a `numpy` array and plot the image.  Then you should be able to add your scatter plot overtop of the image.  [This matplotlib cookbook](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/demo_annotation_box.html) example shows how to insert images and such.  There is also the [matplotlib image tutorial](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/image_tutorial.html) that may be of use.

I've not used it, but you may also be interested in the [basemap toolkit](http://matplotlib.github.com/basemap/) for matplotlib.  In particular, the section on [drawing a map background](http://matplotlib.github.com/basemap/users/geography.html) mentions specifically a `drawcountries()` method.

Comment: Basemap links are broken