# heatmap in matplotlib with vector format

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib, eps

I'm trying to use matplotlib to plot 3D heatmap with results of my simulations. I've read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369492/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set?answertab=active#tab-top) and tried to use imshow. Unfortunately, when I save the figure in SVG or EPS formats, it converts heatmat to picture (which isn't acceptable for journal). So, I've tried  hexbin also - but image is so weird. I'm not sure it will be accepted by journal. Do we have something else, or I have to fill heatmat by rectangles?

For example, if one runs this code:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some test data
x = np.random.randn(8873)
y = np.random.randn(8873)

heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=50)
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]

print extent
print heatmap
plt.clf()
surf = plt.imshow(heatmap, extent=extent)
plt.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.75, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

and save SVG file, it will containe PNG image:

```
   <g clip-path="url(#p6def4f5150)">
    <image height="347" width="315" x="115.127800906" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,
```

I use matplotlib, version 1.1.1 under OpenSUSE and Ubuntu OS.

Comment: @tcaswell I've edited main topic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `pcolormesh` where you're using `imshow` if you want vector output.

When using `pcolor` or `pcolormesh` you can't interpolate the image, however.  On the other hand, you probably don't want interpolation if you're wanting vector output.

That's basically the reason for the difference between `imshow` and `pcolor`/`pcolormesh`. `imshow` produces a raster, while `pcolormesh` and `pcolor` produce rectangular patches.

You'll also need to slightly change the way you pass in the extent of the image. As an example based on yours:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some test data
x = np.random.randn(8873)
y = np.random.randn(8873)

heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=50)

surf = plt.pcolormesh(xedges, yedges, heatmap)
plt.axis('image')
plt.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.75, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

When you save as an svg, the output will be vector patches. E.g.

```
...
   <g id="QuadMesh_1">
    <defs>
     <path d="
M75.9063 -43.2
L82.9705 -43.2
L82.9705 -50.112
L75.9063 -50.112
L75.9063 -43.2" id="C0_0_9d1ab33858"/>
     <path d="
M82.9705 -43.2
L90.0348 -43.2
L90.0348 -50.112
L82.9705 -50.112
L82.9705 -43.2" id="C0_1_d828245e6a"/>
...
```

Comment: thanks! it works! :) Can you explain what this: 'plt.axis('image')'?

Comment: It sets the aspect ratio of the plot to 1 (i.e. square pixels will be square) and trims the limits in.  It's just there so that the output will look similar to `imshow`.