# A logarithmic colorbar in matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make the colors of the points on the scatter plot correspond to the value of the void fraction, but on a logarithmic scale to amplify differences. I did this, but now when I do plt.colorbar(), it displays the log of the void fraction, when I really want the actual void fraction. How can I make a log scale on the colorbar with the appropriate labels of the void fraction, which belongs to [0.00001,1]?

Here is an image of the plot I have now, but the void fraction colorbar is not appropriately labeled to correspond to the true void fraction, instead of the log of it.

[image: current plot]

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x,y,edgecolors='none',s=marker_size,c=np.log(void_fraction))
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Colorbar: void fraction')
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

There is now a section of the documentation describing [how color mapping and normalization works](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html)

The way that `matplotlib` does color mapping is in two steps, first a `Normalize` function (wrapped up by the sub-classes of `matplotlib.colors.Normalize`) which maps the data you hand in to `[0, 1]`.  The second step maps values in `[0,1]` -> RGBA space.

You just need to use the `LogNorm` normalization class, passed in with the `norm` kwarg.

```
plt.scatter(x,y,edgecolors='none',s=marker_size,c=void_fraction,
                norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())
```

When you want to scale/tweak data for plotting, it is better to let `matplotlib` do the transformations than to do it your self.

- `Normalize` [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize)
- `LogNorm` [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LogNorm)
- `matplotlib.color` [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#module-matplotlib.colors)

Comment: The result is in Fig 2. http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2014/cp/c3cp55039g
I added Stack Overflow in the acknowledgements!

Comment: Thank you! IF only the docs hinted at where to look. There are all these fantastic functions with fantastic parameters offering fantastic possibilities but nothing on how to use them.

Comment: Please suggest edits to the docs based on what you now understand

Comment: More easily, you could just pass `norm="log"`.