# reading a tiff file using matplotlib and plotting it in a logarithmic scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, tiff

I use the following program to read an image file using matplotlib and plotting it. However, I do not want the colour scale to be in linear scale, but want to plot it in logarithmic scale. Can anyone please help me in solving this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np



tiff_file = mpimg.imread('D:/image/data_001.tif')
lum_img = tiff_file[:,:,0]
imarray = np.array(tiff_file)
imgplot = plt.imshow(lum_img, cmap='spectral')
plt.colorbar()
```

Thanks.

Comment: This may help: [A logarithmic colorbar in matplotlib scatter plot](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17201172/1730674), which says to use `plt.imshow(..., norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())`

Comment: The reason, I need to have this in logarithmic scale is that the tiff image contains information about x-ray intensity and in linear scale, I hardly see anything. So, I want the information in the tiff data to be displayed in logarithmic scale.

Comment: Askewchan: Thanks for your answer. I tried that command
plt.scatter(x,y,edgecolors='none',s=marker_size,c=np.log(void_fraction))
Here the error for me is x and y. They are not assigned and since it is an array file, I am not sure which one is to be assigned as x and y.

Comment: Keep your call to `imshow` the same as you have it in the question. Only add the `norm=...` argument I showed in my comment above.

Comment: In full, it would be: `plt.imshow(lum_img, cmap='spectral', norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())`

Comment: let me know if it doesn't work. I marked this question as a duplicate, so that anybody who finds your question can find the answer there, but I'm still happy to help you if you need it :) just use `@askewchan` to get my attention.

Comment: @askewchan : Thanks a lot for the help. It helped in changing the scale of the colorbar. I think there is some other fundamental mistake i am doing. The colorbar takes my x-ray intensity values from 0 to 255 instead of the actual information that is stored in it. I will try to find the mistake i am making and get back to you. Once again, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Maybe `data_001.tif` only has values from 0 to 255? Where is the actual x-ray intensity value stored?

Comment: @askewchan : Thanks. You were right. Somehow the tiff image has values from 0 to 255. So, I had to open the tiff file using imageJ and then save it as a txt image file. The .txt file was then imported and plotted. This gave the real values from 0 to few million counts. Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, your tiffs are not 8-bit, but `matplotlib.image.imread` is probably assuming so (and saving as a `dtype='uint8'` array. You don't need to use ImageJ, just find a better image reader, like `PIL` or [`skimage.io.imread`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.io.html#imread), for example.

Comment: @askewchan : PIL works very well and I do not have to convert it from ImageJ. However, for plotting with colormap map and logarithmic scale normalization, I have to use plt. Anyhow everything works fine now. Thanks a lot