# Setting colour scale to log in a contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an array A which I have plotted in a contour plot using X and Y as coordinate axes,

```
plt.contourf(X,Y,A)
```

[image: Contour plot of A]

Problem is, the values in A vary from 1 to a very large number such that the color scale doesn't show a plot. When I plot log(A), I get the following contour,

[image: Contour plot of log(A)]

which is what I'm looking for. But I want to be able to view the values of the array A, instead of log(A), when I hover my cursor over a certain (X,Y) point. I already got an answer for how to do that, but how would I go about doing it while my colour scale remains log? Basically what I'm trying to do is to make the color scale follow a log pattern, but not the array values themselves.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
from matplotlib import colors
plt.contourf(X, Y, A, norm=colors.LogNorm())
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

or

```
from matplotlib import ticker
plt.contourf(X, Y, A, locator=ticker.LogLocator())
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was already asked for log-scaling the colors in a `scatter` plot: [A logarithmic colorbar in matplotlib scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201172/a-logarithmic-colorbar-in-matplotlib-scatter-plot)

As is it was indicated there, there is an article in matplotlibs documentation that describes norms of colormaps: http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/users/colormapnorms.html

Essentially, you can set the norm of your contourplot by adding the keyword `, norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm()`

Comment: Right, surprisingly couldn't find it at first, thanks!