# Is there a tutorial for creating a hexbin heat map using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to learn how to do a heatmap in Python using matplotlib. I'm going to be plotting a series of locations in a huge X,Y grid based off of an array of tuples. I found [this code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369492/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set) which gives a perfect example of what I want to do. I can't seem to understand what the different parts of it mean though. Ultimately I want to output this on an overlay of an existing image. Thanks!

Comment: What are the parts you don't understand? Please specify the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing there is complicated. Anyway, here is a more simplified edition:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

n = 300                                     #number of sample data
x,y = np.random.rand(2,n)                   #generate random sample locations

pl.subplot(121)                             #sub-plot area 1 out of 2
pl.scatter(x,y,lw=0,c='k')                  #darw sample points
pl.axis('image')                            #necessary for correct aspect ratio

pl.subplot(122)                             #sub-plot area 2 out of 2

pl.hexbin(x,y,C=None,gridsize=15,bins=None,mincnt=1)        #hexbinning

pl.scatter(x,y,lw=0.5,c='k',edgecolor='w')  #overlaying the sample points
pl.axis('image')                            #necessary for correct aspect ratio

pl.show()                                   #to show the plot
```

**Sample Points:**
[image: sample points]

**Hexbin result:**
[image: bexbin]

Note that `mincnt=1` avoids plotting hexagon for empty cells. A hexagon cell with dark red has more number of sample points (here 5) inside. Dark blue hexagons have only one sample inside.

Comment: Since OP want it as a translucent overlay, I suggest adding one `imshow()` line and using the `alpha` keyword for `hexbin`.

Comment: I ended up finding a guide that goes into more detail here, http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.html#simple-plot

Comment: Also check out [this brief tutorial](https://github.com/Rblivingstone/datawrangling/blob/master/scatterplots.ipynb)