# Python - Randomly subsamble a range of points to plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have two lists, `x` and `y`, that I wish to plot together in a scatter plot.

The lists contain too many data points. I would like a graph with much less points. I cannot **crop** or **trim** these lists, I need to randomly subsamble a set number of points from both of these lists. What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could subsample the lists using

```
idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(x)), num_samples)
plt.scatter(x[idx], y[idx])
```

However, this leaves the result a bit up to random luck. We can do better by [making a heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2369492/190597). [`plt.hexbin`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin) makes this particularly easy:

```
plt.hexbin(x, y)
```

---

Here is an example, comparing the two methods:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

np.random.seed(2015)
N = 10**5
val1 = np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=2,size=N)
val2 = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
norm = mcolors.LogNorm()

num_samples = 10**4
idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(val1)), num_samples)
ax[0].scatter(val1[idx], val2[idx])
ax[0].set_title('subsample')

im = ax[1].hexbin(val1, val2, gridsize=50, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax[1].set_title('hexbin heatmap')

plt.tight_layout()
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax.ravel().tolist())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The scatter points are discrete so a heatmap cannot be used in my instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can pick randomly from `x` and `y` using a random index mask

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)

# Pick random 10 samples, 2 means two choices from [0, 1] for the mask
subsample = np.random.choice(2, 10).astype(bool)      
plt.scatter(x[subsample], y[subsample])
plt.show()
```

Alternatively you can use `hist2d` to plot a 2D histogram, which uses densities instead of data points

```
plt.hist2d(x, y) # No need to subsample
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [random.sample()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
max_points = len(x)

# Assuming you only want 50 points.
random_indexes = random.sample(range(max_points), 50)

new_x = [x[i] for i in random_indexes]
new_y = [y[i] for i in random_indexes]
```