# How to create a heat map matrix and generate regions based 'heat' in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cluster-analysis, heatmap

Given a set of points (x, y, 'heat'),

```
In [15]: df.head()
Out[15]: 
          x         y      heat
0  0.660055  0.395942  2.368304
1  0.126268  0.187978  6.760261
2  0.174857  0.637188  1.025078
3  0.460085  0.759171  2.635334
4  0.689242  0.173868  4.845778
```

**How to generate a heat map matrix and delimit heat regions (hard)?**

in such a way that, given a point, it is possible to get all points within the same region.

PS:
From [Generate a heatmap in MatPlotLib using a scatter data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369492/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set), I know how to generate graphs of regions, but not how to generate the region 'matrix' (so that given a property, it says in which region it is).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depend how you did the heatmap but assuming you used the first example from the post you linked:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some test data
x = np.random.randn(8873)
y = np.random.randn(8873)

heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=50)
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]

plt.clf()
plt.imshow(heatmap, extent=extent)
plt.show()
```

So you now if you have a request about a point with coords `(a,b)` you need to find the position of the nearest value to `a` in `xedges` (lets call it `a_heatmap`), the position of the nearest value of `b` in `yedges` (`b_heatmap`), then look for the returned value by :

```
heatmap[a_heatmap, b_heatmap]
```

Comment: That is almost what I'm looking for ... but let's assume the region in which the test point '(a,b)' is is the region [5,5] ... but the region might be composed by [5,5],[5,6],[5,7],[6,5],[6.7] ... all with almost the same average 'heat'.

How can I automatically 'merge' regions in order to get 'broader' regions?