# Heatmap with Matplotlib without using pcolor/pmesh

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am reading a text file and from that text file I would like to generate a heat map with [matplotlib](http://www.matplotlib.org). This is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import colors
file_object = open("tokillamockingbird.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
reading = file_object.read()
new_read = reading.strip()
someWord = ''
list_words = []
for letter in new_read:
if letter in ",!.?":
   list_words.append(letter)
lenListWords = len(list_words)
lengthOfPunctuation = math.sqrt(lenListWords)
# generate a scaled plot for this
data = np.random.rand(lengthOfPunctuation,lengthOfPunctuation)
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
```

Up to here, I am stuck and I want to use RGB method in matplotlib to specifiy each color for a 'box' that the scaled plot has.

When I run this it is giving me this picture:

[image: Matplotlib output]

Therefore, how do I add a specific color to a specific box? (if this is 4x4 there will be 16 boxes and I want to know how to put a color to each box)

Comment: Could you provide some data and describe your expected outcome in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the proper command to generate a heatmap, but a 2D plot. If you would have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369492/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set), you would see that it is quite straight forward to generate it. You use (among other things)

```
plt.imshow(heatmap)
plt.show()
```

instead of

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, if you are not fixed on using Matplotlib, you can use [Seaborn](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/index.html), which is another Python package for plotting. It's quite handy for such heatmap based graphics that involve correlations and statistical analysis.

Comment: Was this helpful to you?