# histogram2d heatmap manipulation

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, heatmap, histogram2d

I created a heatmap from a scatterplot of csv values using the code i found from a different stackoverflow thread here [Generate a heatmap in MatPlotLib using a scatter data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369492/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set/20822144)

This works but I'd like to edit the colours/smooth between bins etc. I've read this https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html ...but my level of n00b is preventing swift progress. Does my current code seem ameanable to easy manipulation for interpolation between bins (smoothing) or at least a colour change, or do I need to create my heatmap in a different way to gain more control? (the heatmap will represent how often a space is used in time, based on x y values of a tracked item)
Thanks , any help much appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl


import csv

with open('myfile.csv') as csvfile:
     readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
y = []
x = []
for row in readCSV:  
    x.append(float(row [0]))
    y.append(float(row [1]))

print (x, y)
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x,y,bins=20)
extent  = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]

plt.clf()
plt.imshow(heatmap.T, extent=extent)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.imshow(heatmap.T, extent=extent, interpolation='bicubic')` looking for this?

Comment: The code looks reasonable. What exactly is the question?

Comment: Oh fab @kazemakase thats exactly what I'm looking for.

Such a noob sorry.